# Cannot import resource error, FosRestBundle Throws InvalidArgumentException

Tags: symfony, yaml, fosrestbundle

Hello i have a strange problem, while using FostRestBundle.

First error is :

> InvalidArgumentException: Every parent controller must have `get{SINGULAR}Action($id)` method
>   where {SINGULAR} is a singular form of associated object

And the second one :

> Cannot import resource "/home/a15net/public_html/game/src/ATL/ContentBundle/Resources/config/api_routing.yml" from "/home/a15net/public_html/game/app/config/routing.yml".

I'v checked my all "YAML" files but there was no indent problems.

Tried to update composer twice nothing helped.

Edit : Config.yml > http://goo.gl/dqCAu

Comment: pls share your routing.yml

Comment: Please share your app/config/routing.yml

Comment: @Nisam This service is better : http://chopapp.com/#ruy299p4

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the 'type' from this import statement fro your routing.yml

```
atl_content_api:
    resource: "@ATLContentBundle/Resources/config/api_routing.yml"
```

Inside the api_routing.yml you can specify the rest type for each controller like,

```
acme_user_rest:
    resource: Acme\UserBundle\Controller\UserRestController
    prefix: /api
    type: rest
```

[this](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/setting-up-symfony2-rest-service-with.html) blog will help you to implement the sme

Comment: your post helped me think what i should do. thank you but this is not correct answer. i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**--- NOT --- SOLUTION :**

If a route has a parent route, you must not put "type:rest" to it. You have to use "type:rest" only in parent routes.

Sample :

```
catalogs:
    type: rest
    prefix: api
    resource: ATL\CatalogBundle\Controller\API\CatalogsController
    options:
        expose: true
taxonomy:
    parent: catalogs
    resource: ATL\CatalogBundle\Controller\API\TaxonomyController
    options:
        expose: true
```

I will not choose this as correct answer until more comments and other solution suggestions writed.

**Edit**

> When you remove type:rest from children route, it is not a rest route anymore.

Comment: In the case that you have more than one parent you should ONLY add type:rest to the parent routes. This fixed my problem with multiple nested "parent" routes.